# Edit review audits should contain "obviously" invalid code edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review-audits, rejected-edits

There is a problem with the edit review audits that they only address obvious vandalism - even a simple Bayesian filter could catch whatever audits there are and hit reject on them, and beyond that many reviewers seemingly only look at the reputation of the editor, not on what is being edited.

This leads to [valid edits from newbies](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254673/is-there-a-rationale-for-rejecting-this-code-edit-from-a-new-user) being rejected because the poster has only 1 rep and thus does seem suspicious to someone not well-knowledgeable in the subject matter. However, many view that it is better to be safe than sorry, and thus better to reject a valid than accept an invalid edit.

But there are also [completely invalid code edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4808114) where the well-meaning editor edits away the problems in code; this edit was almost accepted. Could it be possible to somehow get at least these kinds of grossly invalid edits as audits to teach people of the existence of the skip and reject buttons too? This could be manual operation, such as *"Also propose this edit as a review audit"*, which would be available if the edit is being rejected as invalid or too radical.

Comment: I see +3 / -1 but no comments whatsoever.

Comment: 100% agree. I could notice and reject the edit review audits in my sleep. Previously discussed to some extent here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip/

Comment: I just asked the same question again: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281316/fixing-wrong-code-in-peoples-questions Seems all for naught :(