# Are edit rejection rationale comments pre-defined, or entered manually by reviewers?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits, new-users

I've recently made a couple of edits to other users' questions. Naturally, I view the edits as useful, and I realize that others may disagree, and that's fine. What I'm curious about is whether the *rejecting reviewers enter their comments manually*, if they *choose from a fixed list of reasons*, or potentially *both*. I've received rejections (which, again, is fine — that's what the process is for), but the rejection rationale doesn't seem to have any connection to the edits themselves, which makes me think that a list item may be relevant to their rationale but the *description it presents to me* is not.

What makes me ask at all is one case where I've been accused of vandalizing a question or "promoting a service" in a situation where all I really did was revise the title slightly, retag, and condense some pleasantries (which I understand ought not to have been included at all).

Is that shorthand for "insignificant edit," or is there something else going on?

[The comments to this post were useful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254673/is-there-a-rationale-for-rejecting-this-code-edit-from-a-new-user), but I'm wondering more about how the review interface actually works.

To clarify, I'm speaking to the rejection comments *during* the edit-review voting process. Presumably, these votes and their rationale are visible *after* an edit is denied, as well — thankfully, it's never turned out that way for me.

Comment: In any case, I'll take rejection votes to mean that maybe I should be more judicious with my edit suggestions to begin with.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It offers a list of potential options, along with the ability to specify “other”. It looks like this:

[image: rejection dialog, including reasons “spam or vandalism”, “no improvement whatsoever”, “irrelevant tags”, “clearly conflicts with author’s intent”, “attempt to reply”, and a “causes harm” item with a text box]

Comment: If the edit review pane works the same way, then that pretty much answers the question as _both_. I can see how the text presented to reviewers may differ from what it shows the editor. That's very informative; thank you!

Comment: @Augusta: In case you were curious, a suggested edit popped into the queue and I was able to take a screenshot of the dialog (rather than the close dialog I had before).

Comment: Ah, I see-- I was curious, so thanks for the update! That's about what I thought it might look like. I didn't think there'd be _no_ way to add specific review rationale, but I am but a new-user, and that world remains unseen to my tiny eyes~

Comment: Aww, I'm too late for that edit :) (I also got a screen shot of "This was a test" though -- I passed.)