# Should I propose a rejected suggested edit once more?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

A month ago, I'd [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10742414), changing:

> sudo a2enmod cgi; sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

To

> ```
> sudo a2enmod cgi; sudo service apache2 restart
> ```

My edit description was:

> code formatting, replaced init.d call with the wrapper script service,
>   which would make it more portable across versions

Note that the answer says it's on Ubuntu 14.04. On Ubuntu, for several versions now, the `service` command has been a frontend for managing services, which in turn would call the correct `init.d` script, Upstart command or `systemctl` command as needed. Thus, it is safer to use across versions, and better than directly calling an `init.d` script (see [Why use the service command in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312106/why-use-the-service-command-in-linux)).

I am strongly tempted to suggest it again, but a unanimous rejection by three reviewers was a bit unexpected. Any thoughts on how I should go about this? Forget the edit altogether? Suggest again with a better description? Suggest just the code formatting, and forget `service`?

Related:

- [Is there a rationale for rejecting this code edit from a new user?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254673/2072269)

Comment: Just post your own answer, don't forget to explain why it is better.

Comment: @HansPassant why? On what basis would you reject it?

Comment: @Braiam The formatting is good, but the content change is questionable.  I would not know if the content difference is a better way of doing the same thing, or something completely different.

Comment: @Trisped "I would not know" stop! and skip! ;)

Comment: @Braiam If I can't validate your change based on your comments and 5-10 minutes of googling, then you did not do enough to justify your code change.  In most cases code changes only make sense if the code does not work, otherwise you should add a comment or your own answer.  My comment was from the point of view of an editor, so I would not have made the change because the edit would probably get rejected (based on my limited experience).  That said, yes, editors should be willing to skip edits they are not sure about them.

Comment: @Trisped that sounds reasonable.. Except Googling for `service init.d` in a private window has http://askubuntu.com/q/2075 (from 2010) and http://stackoverflow.com/q/22509654 (from 2014) on the first page. Either of those posts will confirm what I wrote in the description, and they recommend using `service`. What's left is to determine when Ubuntu 14.04 was released, and Googling "ubuntu 14.04 release date" shows me the information on a card. You could easily have verified what I said in 5 minutes.

Comment: @Trisped google searching to validate an edit means you don't have the sufficient knowledge to approve or reject the edit. As Braiam said, skip if if you're not sure the edit is correct.

Comment: To me it looks like a different way of achieving the same result with its own advantages and maybe also disadvantages. Posting your own answer may be a better alternative here. Or what about an edit that keeps both variants and explains the pros and cons of each? (For example, in which cases /etc/init.d/apache2 or service apache2 fail, respectively?)

Comment: @Cristik If you read my whole comment, you will see that I stated that.  Both of my comments were indicating that the editor did not do enough to get through the queue, not how to be a reviewer.

Comment: @muru But does the quick google search invalidate the previous solution?  If the original solution works then it deserves to stay.  If needed, notes/warnings could be added as well as alternate solutions in the same vain.

Comment: @Trisped What?! Since when is invalidation of the previous solution the condition for improving it? O.o The original solution "works" in a sense, but can be affected by the environment in unexpected ways. It does not *deserve* anything while the `service` script exists.

Comment: @muru If the solution works (even if it has issues) then removing it does not [leave the post better than you found it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) because you removed information.  If you are not doing one of the 5 things listed, in the link, look for another solution. I think I could have been more clear by saying "If the original solution works then it should stay, since it was the author's original intention." Changing someone else's answer to have a different meaning is not allowed. A comment asking the write why they did not do it your way would allow them to confirm intent.

Comment: @Trisped As I have mentioned twice already in two other comments, OP hasn't been here in over a year.

Comment: @Trisped And those are *common reasons*, not the sole reasons. Nothing in that page suggests that's an exhaustive list.

Comment: @muru The comment "If you are not doing one of the 5 things listed," is to direct you to look for other solutions because you are probably (but not always) using the wrong tool.  The point of my comment was that your edit removes information, which violates the " leave the post better than you found it." authorization granted by the linked article.  Unless you have something else granting you edit authority, then you are not following the rules.

Comment: @Trisped By your interpretation. By my interpretation, I am replacing information, not removing it, and replacing it with better information, because the existing information could cause problems. Unless you have some justification for leaving bad information lying around, I see what I did as being in perfect compliance with the "leave post better than you found it" rule.

Comment: @muru Just so I am clear, if you had added a comment stating where their original solution was useful, then added your code with a description of why it was better, I would find it correct.  The way you did it is generally acceptable, but not good enough to make it through the review queue reliably.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103134/discussion-between-trisped-and-muru).

Comment: @Trisped That is probably the comment you should have posted first. :/

Answer (score 15):

If I were reviewing it I would have rejected it as well, because of the below reason:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

We *shouldn't* change code unless it's a very clear typo (even then I would consider commenting instead). What you can do is suggest that in comments, and it's up to OP whether to consider it or not.

Comment: The OP hasn't been seen since October 2014 according to their profile. I doubt they'd be around to consider such a comment.

Comment: @muru your comment will still be visible for others.

Comment: I'd still argue I'm sticking to the original *intent* of that part of the post,which was restarting `apache` - using `service` would still preserve the OP's goals, and do it in a better way.

Comment: @muru I don't think that's the definition of "intent" in this context.  Regardless of what the question is asking, every detail that the poster posts in terms of code should remain the same unless updated by the poster themselves.  I think that in this context, the edit does overstep its bounds by changing the code itself, which could potentially change the behavior of the entire program.

Comment: @JeremyRodi: I confess unfamiliarity, but would that edit fall under "[To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)"?

Comment: @Deduplicator I would not assume so, given the context; the answer works for a given version of an operating system, and that's never going to change.  However, if the question applies to a newer operating system, then a new answer specifically for that newer operating system should be given, I would think.

Comment: @JeremyRodi The answer "works", but `service` is around for older versions as well, and offers added protection by sanitising the environment before running the script. One could say it is correcting a minor security loophole. (I must note that I'm not on a crusade for `service`, its just good practice and this is a post I actually had use for).

Comment: "We shouldn't change code unless it's a very clear typo" do you have domain knowledge about this particular issue? ["skip it because I don't know the subject well enough to know it's an improvement"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266005/792066)

Comment: @muru the point is that what the original author had posted was exactly what they had tried; by changing the contents of the code, you're changing the behaviour of it, which is not wanted.  If `service` should be used instead, then it should be noted in the comments and the original author should fix it if they deem it needed.

Comment: @JeremyRodi As I have already noted, the original author hasn't been seen here for over a year.

Comment: @muru The original point still stands; just note it in the comments.

Comment: @JeremyRodi I'm sorry, but IMO instructions that are to followed by people should be correct as possible where they read it, not corrected repeatedly in intentionally short-lived entities.

Comment: @muru The answer is correct in the context it was asked; changing the code of the answer changes the context in which it was answered, which is not what we want.

Comment: @JeremyRodi Please explain this "context" to me. Unless you are implying that OP *wanted* the init script to influenced by their environment (in which case they should have explicitly stated so and said which part of the environment they had in mind), the "context" isn't changed at all.

Comment: @muru The "context" of the question is the exact environment, question, tags, and comments on the question that the OP's problems arose from; the "context" of the answer is the solution to the OP's problems, given the environment, question, tags, and comments on the questions that the problem arose from.  The first and foremost responsibility of an answer is to solve the OP's problem, and then be able to be a future solution for others looking for the solution.  Changing the code of the answer changes the context of the answer.

Comment: @JeremyRodi The question that OP's problems arose from does not specify any versions, only Ubuntu, Munin and Apache2. Given that, my edit is all the more correct, since `service` is the most portable way across versions. At this point, I have to ask: what knowledge do you have of init scripts, the `service` commands and managing services on Ubuntu? Because it seems to me, both you and the person who wrote this answer are applying views valid for programming posts to a problem on configuring systems.

Comment: @muru My experience with the topic is decent enough.  I will concede, however, because my stance is a personal stance, and not necessarily one I should impose on you.

Answer (score 8):

Your edit made the answer "timeless". While it may work for some time, it isn't assured. Having yet another answer saying the same with just a tweak, is a disservice for the site, since outdated information will be kept, for the frustration of all users.

**I have domain knowledge of this particular** and applied your edit. Note, don't go around replacing all entries of `/etc/init.d/` for the service since there could be non-compatible systems that you do not know about (which I expect them being increasingly less).

Reviewers, [there are three possible options:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266005/792066)

> - accept it because it may be an improvement
> - reject it as a radical change
> - **skip it because I don't know the subject well enough to know it's an improvement.**

There's no shame in hitting skip.

Comment: Thanks for that. It's incredibly annoying to have all my AU and U&L experience counted for nothing here. :/

Comment: The answer you link to was about an addition to an existing answer, not a rewrite of it. I have the same domain knowledge you have. I still would've rejected the edit suggestion for not leaving enough of the original answer intact. The most I would've approved would be an edit that provides both approaches, because that doesn't have the same problem. I don't think it's *too* bad that you edited it anyway, since I'll admit it's somewhat of an edge case that could go either way. I do think it's bad that you find fault with the reviewers who rejected the edit suggestion.

Comment: @hvd so, when would you ever approve an edit on an answer?

Comment: @Braiam I'd be happy to engage in a productive discussion, but from your reply to my comment, I get a strong impression that's not going to happen anyway, and in that case, I don't have the patience to deal with it right now.

Comment: I agree with @hvd: an edit to an old *answer* by a  low-rep user has to be *very* good and motivated for me to approve it (on the very rare occasion that I review posts; this rarity is partly because I know I'm too strict). The given user can always gain enough rep to fix these problems without approval. That said, I see how the missing rep from the ubuntuish sites must frustrate muru to hell.

Comment: @AndrasDeak the user in particular isn't "low rep user" exactly. He's a moderator on at least one site and with a good standing on two Linux related sites. He should know what he's doing.

Comment: I only know that from this meta post. If I see a suggested edit by a low-rep user, I don't look at their profile to see whether they are really good at DIY or latex. (I completely get your point and fully support their edit, but I don't even think it *should* be routine to check the network profile of suggested editors.). It's clear that I'm not alone with this; I guess the simple solution is for @muru to wait until they reach 2k here before they start fixing the Linux subset of SO:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak I'm not saying that you should, just that one shouldn't have an stance if one is not particularly familiar with the context around an edit. And I would actually hope he reach 3k first, so he can help with the cleanups.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I'd agree with you an that, but the level of opposition to this change troubles me a great deal. It seems to me that SO has diverged considerably from how edits are seen on [ubuntu.se] or [unix.se]. I'd bet that such an edit would have been welcome on these sites any day. Or perhaps it's these two that have diverged. (Again, I'd like to note that I'm not on a crusade to fix uses of init scripts, or any other Linux-related part here).

Comment: This is not just about context. I'm not that versed in the area like you, but it would've been clear to me that it's better to do it in the suggested way. Without knowing the reason why, I know that using `service` is the proper way to do it. But unless there's a serious flaw (such as security, or danger of being abducted by aliens), I'm very conservative with suggested edits to answers (and the edit comment didn't convey that it's paramount to make this edit). This might suggest what @muru just noted: that the edit culture is much different here than on AU and U&L. (Or maybe I'm just a jerk)

Comment: @AndrasDeak [you, kind sir, are a jerk... **and that's cool!**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/08/stack-exchange-is-not-a-forum-the-role-of-niceness-on-a-qa-site/)

Comment: "Your edit made the answer "timeless". While it may work for some time, it isn't assured." Hmm, somehow "timeless" and "may work for some time" do not seem to work together in my mind.

Comment: @Trilarion it means that it converted something that may break tomorrow (due random things), into something that will not break in the foreseeable future.